geodesics on the Riemann sphere and tangents on the complex plane
We are given two points $z$ and $w$ on the complex plane. Inverse stereographic projection maps these 2 points to $M$ and $N$ on $S^2$. There is a simple expression for the chord length on the sphere between these 2 points just using $z$ and $w$ directly:
https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere
$$\chi(z,w)=\frac{2 |z-w|}{\sqrt{|z|^2+1}\sqrt{|w|^2+1}}$$
We can draw a great circle segment joining $M$ and $N$ and project it to the complex plane. We obtain a circle or line joining $z$ and $w$. Can we find a nice expression for the tangent of that circle or line at $z$ and $w$ again using complex numbers?

The tangent to a line is the line, so that case is pretty easy, and even more so when you realize that it only occurs when the great circle passes through $\infty$, and therefore also through $0$. Hence the projected line passes through $0$, and either $z$ or $w$ is $0$, or $\frac zw$ is real. Assuming $z \ne 0$, the line is parametrically $t \mapsto tz$.
When $z, w$ are not collinear with $0$, we can set $z = z_1 +iz_2, w = w_1 + i w_2$ and define $z_3 = \frac{|z|^2 - 1}2, w_3 = \frac{|w|^2 - 1}2$, then the projected points on the sphere are $\frac{(2z_1, 2z_2, 2z_3)}{|z|^2 + 1},\frac{(2w_1, 2w_2, 2w_3)}{|w|^2 + 1}$. The great circle passing through them is the intersection of the sphere with the plane through the origin perpendicular to the vector $$(z_1, z_2, z_3) \times (w_1, w_2, w_3) = (z_2w_3-w_2z_3, z_3w_1-w_3z_1, z_1w_2-w_1z_2)$$ A point $(x,y,z)$ is on that great circle if and only if $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $$(z_2w_3-w_2z_3)x + (z_3w_1-w_3z_1)y + (z_1w_2-w_1z_2)z = 0$$
If $(x,y,z)$ is the projection of a complex number $u + iv$, then $x = \frac{2u}{u^2 + v^2 + 1}, y = \frac{2v}{u^2 + v^2 + 1}, z = \frac{u^2 + v^2 -1}{u^2 + v^2 + 1}$, so the plane equation becomes
$$2(z_2w_3-w_2z_3)u + 2(z_3w_1-w_3z_1)v + (z_1w_2-w_1z_2)(u^2 + v^2 - 1) = 0$$
Completing the squares on $u$ and $v$ gives the center of the circle to be at $(\frac{z_2w_3-w_2z_3}{z_1w_2-w_1z_2})+i(\frac{z_3w_1-w_3z_1}{z_1w_2-w_1z_2})$.
Plugging in the definitions of $z_2, w_3$ and going through some tedious calculations, the center can be expressed as $$i\frac{zw(\bar z - \bar w) + z - w}{\bar z w - z\bar w}$$
The tangent line at $z$ and $w$ will of course be perpendicular to the line through the point and the center.

Since we are dealing with a great circle, we know that the antipodes of the points $M$ and $N$ also lie on the same great circle. These antipodes are mapped to $-\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ and $-\frac{1}{\bar{w}}$.
Circles on the sphere are mapped to circles and lines of the complex plane by stereographic projection. We can now compute the tangent at $z$ using the 3 point arc/line going through the points $-\frac{1}{\bar{w}}$, $z$ and $w$. We use the method from 3.1 in https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/PAPERS/JCAD05_CircleSplines.pdf avoiding the computation of the center, treating both the arc and line cases in one go.
Translating into complex numbers to compute the tangent at z we obtain before normalization
$$\frac{(w-z) \left(\frac{1}{\bar{w}}+z\right)}{\frac{1}{\bar{w}}+w}$$
Normalizing and simplifying
$$t_z=\frac{(w-z)(1+z\bar{w})}{|(w-z)(1+z\bar{w})|}$$
Proceeding the same way with $z$,$w$ and $-\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$, we obtain
$$t_w=\frac{(w-z)(1+\bar{z}w)}{|(w-z)(1+\bar{z}w)|}$$
